# Scheme function for adding elements in nested list

Tags: scheme, racket, paradigms

I'm trying to create a scheme program that adds the elements of a given list (both simple and nested).

```
(define (adder a_list)
  (cond
    ((null? a_list) 0)
    ((list? (car a_list))(adder (car a_list)))
    (else (+ (car a_list) (adder (cdr a_list))))
    )
  )
```

(adder '(2 (5 4) 6))```

The problem I'm running into is that when I run this, it only adds (5+4) + 2, and then doesn't add the 6. So my output is 11 rather than 17. I know my null statement at the top is causing this issue, but when I take it out I get this error:

```
  car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: '()
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, translated: the sum of the empty list is 0; the sum of a list whose first element is a list is the sum of only its first element; and for everything else, add the first element to the sum of the tail. (The null case is actually correct; your problem is the second case.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (adder a*)
  (if (null? a*)
      0
      (+ (if (pair? (car a*))
             (adder (car a*))
             (car a*))
         (adder (cdr a*)))))
```

And, shorter:

```
(define ++
  (lambda (a*)
    (fold-left (lambda (a x)
                 (+ a (if (pair? x) (++ x) x)))
               0
               a*)))
```

(written in *mit/scheme*)

Comment: I think `fold-left` is more powerful than you really need here. Just do a `map` phase first, to turn any nested lists into their sum, and then `(apply +)` the resulting list. `(define (++ x) (if (pair? x) (apply + (map ++ x)) x))`

Comment: @amalloy While syntactically it is simpler, I think semantically it is more complex, as `map` acummulates lists that are passed to _apply_, while the `folds` do not pass the full lists but use only an accummulator register that is returned at the end.